# Addition of Binary Numbers in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary, addition

I need to create a function to add a binary number to another one. It's a task for my study and I'm not that much into Haskell and could use some help.

I already made the datatype which I have to use.

```hs
data B = Zero
    | Even B
    | Odd B
    deriving (Show, Generic)
instance Listable B where tiers = genericTiers
```

`Even` means 0, `Odd` means 1 and `Zero` is the end.

..so for example Odd(Even(Odd Zero))) is equal to 101
... and that is my function so far.

```hs
plusB :: B -> B -> B
plusB (Odd a) (Odd b) = Odd (Even (plusB a b))
plusB (Even a) (Even b) =  Even (plusB a b)
plusB (Even a) (Odd b) = Odd (plusB a b)
plusB (Odd a) (Even b) = Odd (plusB a b)
plusB (Zero) (Zero) = .....
```

I think that I have to use recursion for it to work.

I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Well you likely should work with *two* parameters here, since your function adds two numbers together.

Comment: I don't understand your code at all. First, I don't understand your data type: what does `Odd $ Even $ Odd $ Odd Zero` represent? Second, why derive `Generic`? Third, you declare `plusB :: B -> B -> B`, but your implementations have the type `B -> B` instead of `B -> B -> B`. Finally, `(plusB x)` and `((plusB x))` are equivalent, which seems unlikely to be correct.

Comment: @AndrewRay The type is isomorphic to `[Bool]`, and it's pretty easy to translate that to a binary number. The number you ask about is either 1011, or 1101, depending on whether the intended encoding is LSB first or last.

Comment: This is really more of an algorithm question, rather than a Haskell one. What you currently have is basically a [half adder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Half_adder); read up on how to extend that to a full adder. If you have a question regarding a concrete problem in you implementation for that in Haskell, _that_ could make for a good question here.

Answer (score 1):

If you assume that the `Even` constructor returns the image of an *even* number, and that the `Odd` constructor returns the image of an *odd* number, this implies that the outermost constructor maps to the rightmost (least significant) bit.

In that case, more descriptive names for `Odd` and `Even` could be `Twice` and `TwicePlus1`.

Mapping B objects to Integers:

```
toIntegerFromB :: B -> Integer
toIntegerFromB  Zero    =  0
toIntegerFromB (Even x) =  2*(toIntegerFromB x)
toIntegerFromB (Odd x)  =  1 + 2*(toIntegerFromB x)
```

As for the addition of two B objects:

```
plusB :: B -> B -> B
```

we have 3*3 = 9 equations to write. But 5 of them involves `Zero` which is the neutral element, and so are quite easy to write:

```
plusB  (Zero)    (Zero)     =  Zero
plusB  (Zero)    (Even a)   =  Even a
plusB  (Even a)  (Zero)     =  Even a
plusB  (Zero)    (Odd a)    =  Odd a
plusB  (Odd a)   (Zero)     =  Odd a
```

Regarding the 4 remaining equations, we note that number 1 maps to `Odd Zero` and that number 2 maps to `Even (Odd Zero)`.

Thinking of `Odd` and `Even` as `TwicePlus1` and `Twice` respectively:

(Odd a) + (Odd b) ≃ (2*a+1)+(2*b+1) = 2 + 2*(a+b) ≃ Even (Odd Zero) + Even (a+b)

Hence the equation:

```
plusB  (Odd a)   (Odd b)    =  plusB  (Even (Odd Zero))  (Even (plusB a b))
```

Next, we have:

(Odd a) + (Even b) ≃ (2*a + 1) + (2*b) = 1 + 2*(a+b) ≃ Odd (a+b)

Hence, using symmetry, the 2 equations:

```
plusB  (Even a)  (Odd b)    =  Odd  (plusB a b)
plusB  (Odd a)   (Even b)   =  Odd  (plusB a b)
```

The last remaining equation is easier:

(Even a) + (Even b) ≃ (2*a)+(2*b) = 2*(a+b) ≃ Even (a+b)

```
plusB  (Even a)  (Even b)   =  Even (plusB a b)
```

### Putting it all together:

```
plusB :: B -> B -> B
plusB  (Zero)    (Zero)     =  Zero
plusB  (Zero)    (Even a)   =  Even a
plusB  (Even a)  (Zero)     =  Even a
plusB  (Zero)    (Odd a)    =  Odd a
plusB  (Odd a)   (Zero)     =  Odd a
plusB  (Odd a)   (Odd b)    =  plusB  (Even (Odd Zero))  (Even (plusB a b))
plusB  (Even a)  (Even b)   =  Even (plusB a b)
plusB  (Even a)  (Odd b)    =  Odd  (plusB a b)
plusB  (Odd a)   (Even b)   =  Odd  (plusB a b)
```

Compared to the more common `data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat`, this representation has the nice advantage of requiring only O(log(n)) nested constructors, instead of O(n).